# import img vs require image in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a react application. I noticed on different screens when I load, the images always load slightly delayed and populate as the page is loaded. It's quick, but it's noticeable.

I'm wondering if this has to do with how my images are being called / imported?

an example of how mine are being used in this component

```
import meatIcon from '../../icons/meat.png'
import crustIcon from '../../icons/crust.png'
import sizeIcon from '../../icons/size_tape.png'
//... + many more
```

or is it more efficient to start doing something such as this

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```